# Uninstalling MySql on mac os x without the Root password

Tags: sql, osx-yosemite

when i try command to remove MySql it is asking for password which i forgot.[Screen shot says it all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0gDU.png). Can some one help me go through this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to reset your root password:

Here is an tutorial how to do without any install disk.
Boot into single user mode and reset it, then you will be able to uninstall mysql:

http://www.macyourself.com/2009/08/03/how-to-reset-your-mac-os-x-password-without-an-installer-disc/